# How to use array modifier with follow path constraint (Cableway Chairs)

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, constraints

I am making a ski lift, pictured below. For the chairs, I am hoping to use a mix of an array modifier and a follow path constraint.[image: Description]

I have tried to use a curve modifier, but this offsets the whole thing which isn't what I want either. I would really appreciate any advice on how to solve this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A simple *Array* modifier will deform your object, so you can use 2 methods:

**With Follow Path constraint**:

- Give your chair a *Follow Path* constraint.
- Duplicate your object with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> (linked duplication), and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> so that the copy stays at the exact same position.
- Play with the constraint *Offset* value to place the copy before or after the original object.

**With Duplifaces**:

- Create a curve. Put its origin to its beginning point to make it easier.
- Create a plane at the exact same point. This plane will be used as a base for your chair.
- Apply the curve and the plane scales.
- Give the plane an *Array* modifier, choose *Constant Offset* or the *Relative Offset* value, choose the *Count* value.
- Give the plane a *Curve* modifier with the curve as *Object*. The plane should be duplicated along the curve.
- Keep the plane selected and in the *Properties* panel > *Object* > *Instancing*, activate *Faces*.
- Parent the chair object to the plane, the chair should be duplicated on the planes.
- If you want the chair to stay vertical along the curve, create a single vertex instead of a plane.
- To animate, move the plane on the right axis.