# Why the mesh bend as it follow curve

Tags: bezier-curves

Few days before i had this same issue and got the [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183263/mesh-bend-as-it-follow-curve-along-path/183268?noredirect=1#comment306689_183268)

[image]

I tried the same for this mesh but did not work.

[image]

I on the z-up option still the mesh bend as it follow the curve. The radius scale rotation are all 0.

Any suggestion or help. Thanks

Comment: Actually Z-Up didn't completely fix your previous problem because your object was still not completely vertical, I don't know how it is calculated but anyway it looks like this time it doesn't work at all, so maybe you'll have to use another method like array + curve for a simple plane, then instance your object on this plane

Comment: @moonboots but its simple mesh and a simple curve.

Comment: Follow curve will always deform your object. That is how it works. @moonboots advise is the way to go. In 2.79 there was dupliframes, but in 2.8 you can do a plane follow the array and instance the object on the plane. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/175913/92768